# Looking for advice on how to move stepper motor on TTL signal reception?

Tags: stepper-motor

I have a full-blown motor controller that moves a stepper motor ; it is able
to receive a TTL signal (3 volts, raising edge) to trigger a +500 steps
motion on the stepper motor. It is also able to do a home signal search to
put the system at a known position.

*EDIT*: the stepper motor is bipolar, 2000 steps for 360 degrees

Speed and acceleration are fixed, and configured since the beginning.

This motor controller is quite expensive and I have the feeling the same can
be done very easily with another piece of hardware ; but I have no idea
where to look for.

I am a software engineer so I don't mind having to write some code to make
it work.

I looked at a [Wago controller](http://www.automation.com/product-showcase/wago-io-module-eliminates-motion-controller) ; I imagine a lot of simpler alternatives exist.
I am looking for a simple
stepper motor controller with external TTL input to trigger a configured
motion, or some more DIY solution.

It seems I can also use something based on a Raspberry PI: https://www.pololu.com/product/2753

Comment: There are a myriad of DIY options as well as some very nice chips and modules available.  You do need to find out whether you have a uni-polar or bipolar stepper motor - this determines the type of driver you need.

Comment: This question will be closed for a variety of reasons. See the Help Center for allowable questions. Figure out what motor you have, research H-bridge stepper drivers and come back with a specific question.

Comment: But generally, building a motor driver from scratch is not an easy task even for somewhat experienced EEs.

Comment: @DwayneReid: thanks for your help. As I edited the question, it is a bipolar stepper. Could you please give me some links where I can have a look for drivers?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: indeed. I am looking for a cheap yet efficient way of driving the motor - I am lost with all what exists on the market and I am a very beginner in stepper motors driving so any help would be appreciated

Comment: My favourite small bipolar stepper driver module is from Pololu - it's a TI driver chip DRV8825 on a carrier board.  Very inexpensive and works extremely well for stepper motors up to 2 Amps.   https://www.pololu.com/product/2133

Comment: Thanks @DwayneReid I am now looking at this driver chip... I edited my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of simple stepper controllers out there that take a TTL step signal and advance the motor a single step and a second signal for direction. They often allow a user definable level of micro-stepping.

You can either buy the chips (normally surface mount with a big pad underneath the part so they get better heatsinking to the pcb and so tricky to hand solder) or you can get modules with the part on that you can then connect to.
e.g. https://github.com/watterott/SilentStepStick

You then need to add the software control to pulse the step signal at the correct frequency to give the rate of turn you require. Constant velocities are trivial, getting the timing correct for smooth accelerations gets a little more complex but isn't too bad.

Knowing your current heading is simply a case of counting the number of steps assuming you haven't slipped due to trying to accelerate too fast.